# Change DLL File Version of Website Application before precompiling

Tags: c#, asp.net

After precompiled, my asp.net webiste application's bin folder contains the dlls with file version 0.0.0.0. How can I set a file version something like 2.1.1.0.

In 'Property Page' (by right click on solution) there is no option to set the file version. But in a Class library project I could set the file version in 'Property' page.

Then, how can I do in case of a website application before precompiling?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Web Deployment Projects](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/06/429723.aspx) to precompile your the site there's a possibility to specify the output assembly version in the properties page of the project. If you are using [aspnet_compiler.exe](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/06/429723.aspx) you could create an AssemblyInfo.cs file and use [AssemblyVersionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx).